# Android permissions for pinging network

Tags: android, permissions, manifest, ping

I'm working on android app which do some pings on LAN, using C# System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping class. What kind of android manifest permission do I need? For now I have only android.permission.INTERNET, but it seems not enought.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I've tried to add android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_CONDITIONS - but still can't ping.

Answer (score 0):

add these two permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```